# Snack time, protein or carbs?

Tags: diet, snacks

I have finally come back into meal prep mode, and before I never actually gave thought of the order of my snacks or if it matters at all, I usually have a protein or carb snack with some green tea. The time I'm aiming for is 11am for first snack and 5pm for second snack. But I was wondering, does it matter if I eat the protein snack first? or should I eat the carb one first? I go to the gym around 7pm, if that helps to give some insight. Other than my whey protein I haven't found a good substitute to consider switching the protein snack options. So any suggestions will be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand-the snack has both protein and carbs, or each snack consists on one but not the other?

Comment: the latter @DaveNewton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No meal timing does not matter , only concern would be if you have energy at the gym. You may find you have more energy consuming carbs a few hours before. Other than that there is no difference.
For protein other than whey, I use Greek yogurt , sometimes i make protein pancakes . you can Google for recipes

Answer (score 1):

Taking the assumption of a carb-bar and a protein-bar where there is no crossover: Carbs (when presented in bar form) usually give you fast energy, and is the primary reason they are popular with outdoor sport enthusiasts.

A protein bar is usually intended as a supplement to your diet to replace what carbs you would have ingested, with protein. Protein on its own doesn't usually give you a lot of energy but it helps your body with recovery. This is why it is commonly accepted that around 30 minutes after weightlifting, drink a protein shake.

As with all of this, follow the principle of "If it meets your macros". If you are getting enough protein from your diet. Simply, aim for

- 0.8-1g protein per pound body weight
- 0.35-0.45g fat per pound body weight
- 0.7-0.9 carbs per pound body weight

source: http://www.iifym.com/

You should be able to easily get your protein for the day by eating lean meat and dairy.